# Nested CASE statement in the WHERE clause

Tags: sql, oracle, switch-statement

I am trying to use NESTED CASE statement(BOLD Below) where, based on first CASE statment, I need to verify inner where clause, else other inner where clause. Is below right approach when using nested CASE When statements?

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   <list of table>
WHERE  <list of conditions > 
AND    CASE  WHEN cond1 <> 1 or cond2 <>2 or cond3 <> 3
             THEN 
                WHEN ( col1,col2,col3) NOT IN (SELECT col1,col2,col3
                                               FROM   table 1,table 2
                                               WHERE  <condition1> )
                ELSE ( col1,col2,col3,col4) NOT IN (SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4
                                                    FROM   table 1,table 2
                                                    WHERE  <condition2> )
             END
```

Comment: Please do not SHOUT when posting here. Text in ALL CAPS is more difficult to read and understand, and SHOUTING will not get you help any faster. It's also rather impolite to SHOUT at the people you're asking for **free help** to solve  **your problem**. Thanks.

Comment: That's a `case` _expression_, not statement. However, use regular AND/OR instead, like in MT0's answer below.

Comment: @Ken, I never shouted to anyone in my life. You guys are here to help, how can i shout on you.  text in CAPS may be typo so please ignore...... Help is Help......I have not heard a word call "free help".  if you pay for help that become service.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `AND` and `OR`:

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM   <list of table>
WHERE  <list of conditions > 
AND    (  (   ( cond1 <> 1 OR cond2 <> 2 OR cond3 <> 3 )
          AND (col1,col2,col3) NOT IN (SELECT col1,col2,col3
                                       FROM   table1
                                              INNER JOIN table2
                                              ON (<condition>)
                                       WHERE  <condition1>)
          )
       OR (   NOT ( cond1 <> 1 OR cond2 <> 2 OR cond3 <> 3 )
          AND (col1,col2,col3,col4) NOT IN (SELECT col1,col2,col3,col4
                                            FROM   table1
                                                   INNER JOIN table2
                                                   ON (<condition2>)
                                            WHERE  <condition2> )
          )
       )
```

*Notes: Do not use legacy comma joins, use the modern ANSI join syntax.*

Comment: You are a genius MT0, Thanks you made is so easy...........